# Web Chat: Avatar initials and image not showing

Tags: botframework

I have created a bot with MS Bot Framework and now I want to use Web Chat as a channel. Unfortunately adding avatar initials and images does not seem to work for me as it should according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-webchat-customization?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#change-the-avatar-of-the-bot-within-the-dialog-box).

Here is the very simple code from the documentation using botAvatarInitials to pass on the initials:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
      <div id="webchat" role="main"></div>
      <script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/webchat.js"></script>
      <script>
         window.WebChat.renderWebChat(
            {
               directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({
                  secret: 'YOUR_BOT_SECRET'
               }),

               // Passing avatar initials when rendering Web Chat
               botAvatarInitials: 'BF',
               userAvatarInitials: 'WC'
            },
            document.getElementById('webchat')
         );
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is documented incorrectly. The `botAvatarInitials` and the `userAvatarInitials` need to be set in the style options.

```
const styleOptions = {
  botAvatarInitials: 'BF',
  userAvatarInitials: 'WC'
};

window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
    directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({secret: 'YOUR_BOT_SECRET'}),
    styleOptions
  },
  document.getElementById('webchat')
);
```

For more details, take a look at the [Display User and Bot Initials](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/04.a.display-user-bot-initials-styling) Web Chat sample.

Comment: what about avatar images?

Comment: @hkhan Take a look at [this](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/02.branding-styling-and-customization/d.display-sender-images) Web Chat sample.